# Ubuntu 14.04.3 install fail

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation

I am using legacy boot.  I install server 14.04.3 but when I reboot I get nothing.  It never boots and never gives up and tries netboot, it just hangs, black screen.  It appears to be a hardware issue as the ssd boots fine and works in an older machine.

I just confirmed that if I install server 14.04.1 from USB it works fine and boots but unfortunately hangs partway through the boot process.  Again the SSD boots fine and works as expected in the older machine.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the boot device / boot order in the bios. Also make sure the boot loader is installed on the right disk/partition.

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer OP says it hangs on loading, and doesn't hit the PXE boot stage.

Comment: @Zacharee1 OP says it never boots and never gives up and tries netboot. As I read it, the bios didn't find a bootable drive and tries netboot.  So it DOES hit the PXE boot and keeps trying without giving up.

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer if it never gives up, how does it hit PXE?

Comment: @Zacharee1 PXE will keep trying to find a PXE server. Without any luck in the case explained here because it should boot from SSD.

Comment: @E.F.Nijboer I don't think that's what it's saying at all. In any case, it's completely unclear and should be closed

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like a hardware issue, especially since you say it works just fine when used in another computer.

Are you able to verify that the SSD is indeed showing up in BIOS, and that your boot order is set up correctly?

Comment: The SSD shows up in the list in BIOS.  The order is SSD, network, optical.  If I change the order to net first it attempts a network boot.

Comment: I would, as mentioned, say this is a hardware issue. Unfortunately, that is not my expertise. Maybe someone else here has more experience with this than me. I wish you good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.  Firstly I was using a pxe boot server to do the install.  The pxe server was using a base install from 14.04.1 and upgrading.  When I installed directly from USB using server 14.04.1 the install would hang after its first reboot.  Even though apt-get upgraded it to 14.04.3.  It would work OK on old hardware.

After trying a direct install using 14.04.1 and 14.04.3 from ISOs, I found that only a direct install from 14.04.3 would work on this hardware.

*On further investigation I found that the problem was the nouveau driver. The system was being installed OK but the console never appeared. Since it was a server there was no GUI and it appeared to be hung.*